# How can I randomise my MAC address in response to probe requests?

Tags: wireless, networking

I read recently that iOS 8 devices will randomise their MAC addresses when probed.

> In iOS8, Wi-Fi scanning behavior has changed to use random, locally administrated MAC addresses
>
> Probe requests (management frame sub-type 0x4)
>   Probe responses (management frame sub-type 0x5)
>
> The MAC address used for Wi-Fi scans may not always be the device's real (universal) address
>
> (source: [Ars Technica](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2014/06/ios8-to-stymie-trackers-and-marketers-with-mac-address-randomization/))

I'd like to avoid advertracking, annoy my sysadmin at the office and keep up with the Joneses. Is it possible to configure Ubuntu to do this or something similar?

Comment: Why on earth does iOS 8 do THAT?! I see little to no security boost there, except that the device is harder to administer.

Comment: ...so you want a constant macchanger?